# Coulomb Barrier - Nuclear Physics

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, nuclear-physics, quantum-chemistry

When we calculate the Coulomb's barrier we usually assume that two nucleus (target and projectile) just touch each other so the barrier:

$$E_{cb}=\frac{0.96Z_1 Z_2}{A_1 ^{1/3}+A_2^{1/3}}\text{ MeV} \tag 1$$

But when the centre of mass is not considered immobile then within that model we have the coulomb barrier (conservation of momentum is there) and $A_2$ is mass number of target nucleus:

$$ E_{cb}=\frac{1.109Z_1 Z_2 (A_1+A_2 )}{A_2 (A_1^{1/3}+A_2^{1/3})}\text{ MeV} \tag 2$$

I saw this second equation(2) in this link: 
[Energetics of Nuclear Reaction (Page-338)](http://jol.liljenzin.se/KAPITEL/CH12NY3.PDF)
This link is part of the Book "Radiochemistry and Nuclear Chemistry"

I was able to derive the minimum kinetic energy(second equation) required in the lab frame from the minimum kinetic energy required(first equation) in center of mass frame(of the target and projectile system) for the nuclear reaction to occur.

But from what I derived, my second equation doesn't contain 1.109 instead it contains 0.96, and I have no idea why in the original link 1.109 is coming, so please help.

Comment: Have you tried transforming from the center of mass frame to the lab frame?